# Pending Status | Pod Unschedulable | Untolerated Taint

Tags: openshift

I have been doing some exercises with PODs in the OpenShift Developer Sandbox. During my last exercise I attempted to create a POD with this YAML :

[image: Taints_and_Affinity]

But unfortunately I gon the following error:

"Pod unschedulable
0/12 nodes are available: 2 node(s) had untolerated taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/infra: }, 3 node(s) had untolerated taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, 7 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/12 nodes are available: 12 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.."

[image: POD unscheduled]

Now, I know that a pending state means that this pod is waiting to be scheduled on ​​a node. And this might happen for several reasons:

- there is no node available with the resources required: CPU and memory
- the pod is waiting for its images to be extracted
- the pod is waiting for its dependencies to be initialized
- the pod is waiting for a specific node to become available

I should probably be checking the logs for errors or warnings and if there are no errors I probably should be increasing the number of nodes in the cluster to reduce the resource requirements of the pod.

The problem is, I don't know how to do that in the OpenShift Developer Sandbox.
In case someone could help me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Does you nodes has the value `node-with-enough-memory` with key `kubernetes.io/hostname`?